# facebook chat on the iphone using xmppframework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, chat

Well i started of by following all the instructions here:
http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo

I used the recommended fork of the facebook api and tried the latest from:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

My problem starts with the following error:

```
< failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">< not-authorized/></failure>
```

The error is a reply from facebook to xmppframework s response to a authentication challenge. The response that is made by the iphone is base64 encoded msg when i decode it i find 2 of the values are null:
api_key=(null)
and the
session_key=(null)

This is obviously the reason facebook is returning that error. But the problem i have is i cant seem to find any where to set these values in the framework. Besides i think the session_key should be pulled in from facebook anyway.

I guess what i want to know is a couple of things.

Has any one got the xmppframework working with facebook on a iDevice?

If you have got it working did you have to stray from the path of the instructions on http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo   ?

do you know of any other method to get facebook chat working on the iphone?

Any suggestions or help for my current dilemma would be appreciated. Happy to share my code if you want.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the Facebook integration for XMPPFramework.  The api_key and session_key, come from a call to auth.PromoteSession.  Facebook is trying to deprecate that call, so to enable it, you must follow step 7, in the HowTo:

1. Under Migrations, change Disable Deprecated Auth Methods from Enabled to Disabled and Save Changes.

Comment: I did use the deprecated api. Will re check the api and session. thx

Comment: We've updated XMPPFramework to work with Facebook's OAuth 2.0 changes of October 1st, 2011.  The new process is much simpler and documented in the code and on the wiki.